# Cypress - don't record video when pass

Tags: automation, cypress

I'm trying to configure video recording option in Cypress. I added below configuration to Cypress.json file as below.

```
{  
  "videoUploadOnPasses": false
}
```

But it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you verify your folder structure? Where Cypress.json is placed (Ideally it should be placed in root)

Comment: Other parameters are working properly. This one is only that doesn't work.

Comment: This is a known thing with Cypress, there have been a few issues opened with their github project for this.  See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2522 and the issues that are linked from that one.

Give the issue a thumbs up to show you would like it fixed!

Comment: this parameter is for something else: 

Whether Cypress will process, compress, and upload videos to the Dashboard even when all tests in a spec file are passing. This only applies when recording your runs to the Dashboard. Turn this off if you’d like to only upload the spec file’s video when there are failing tests.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Although "cypress.json" at root folder has `"videoUploadOnPasses": false`, cypress saves video for passing tests. (v4.5.0)

Comment: I still encounter this issue